# Let $X$ be any subset of the real line, and let $Y$ be a set such that $X\subseteq Y \subseteq \bar{X}$. Show that $\bar{Y}=\bar{X}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ be any subset of the real line, and let $Y$ be a set such that $X\subseteq Y \subseteq \bar{X}$. Show that $\bar{Y}=\bar{X}$

### My attempt:

$\bar{X}$ is defined to be the set of all the adherent points of $X$. We say that $x$ is an adherent point of $X$ iff it is $\epsilon$-adherent to $X$ for every $\epsilon>0$. We say that $x$ is $\epsilon$-adherent to $X$ iff there exists a $y\in X$ which is $\epsilon$-close to $x$. (ex. $|x-y|\leq \epsilon$).

Let $X$ and $Y$ be arbitrary subsets of the real line. Then $X\subseteq \bar{X}$. Also if $X\subseteq Y$ then $\bar{X} \subseteq \bar{Y}$.

I am not really sure where to go from here

Comment: Do you know that $\overline{\overline{X}}=\overline{X}$?

Comment: Use the above and $A\subset B\Rightarrow \bar{A}\subset \bar{B}$.

Comment: So $X\subset Y$ imples $\bar{X} \subset \bar{Y}$

Answer (score 1):

$X\subset Y\subset \overline{X}$, so taking closures, $\overline{X}\subset \overline{Y}\subset \overline{X}$, since $\overline{X}$ is closed.